# A Tale of Prehistoric Times

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

> Gather round if you want to know
>   A tale of creatures from long ago
>   This rhyme is of the greatest beast
>   To rule the land from West to East
>   All creatures then would tend to run
>   To see the beast, their lives were done
>   The reason for their utmost fear?
>   That one day the great beast did tear
>   Apart the ground on which it stood
>   And fought the sky but lost for good
>   Great duty conferred that accursed date
>   All its size and power doubled with hate
>   Till at last the whole world it
>   Covered each mile bit by bit
>   Tell me: how is the name writ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first letter of each line

> Form a DNA sequence. Taking the first letter of the amino acid represented by each triplet spells **ATLAS**, the answer.
>
>  `GAT Aspartic Acid`
>  `TAT Tyrosine`
>  `TTA Leucine`
>  `AGA Arginine`
>  `TCT Serine`

Comment: That was *fast*. Maybe you'd like to explain why it's thematic/how the title relates?